Fetching the other TFS branch one by one
I've almost managed to migrate all my repos from TFS to Git but I've got an issue with a big one that after 3 hours gives me an error on CacheFull on a specific branch.
I've read I can clone the main and then add all the needed one by one but I've a problem with the syntax...
Using git-tfs list-remote-branches shows me for example
 | 
 +- $/Project1/Releases/2.2
 | 
 +- $/Project1/Releases/2.3.0.4
 | 
 +- $/Project1/XXX/DEV

Then I've done
git tfs clone http://tfs:8080/tfs/collection $/Project1/XXX/Main . --branches=none
and it cloned the master.
Now I've tried using git fetch -i $/Project1/Releases/2.2 but I got an error saying
Unable to locate git-tfs remote with id =  $/Project1/Releases/2.2
You may be able to resolve this problem.

Try using git tfs bootstrap to auto-init TFS remotes.

I've also tried doing git tfs bootstrap and doing again the fetch but without luck
Any suggestion? or how can I tell to skip for example $/Project1/XXX/DEV and $/Project1/XXX/FOO_3 in case I got in a loop with them?
Thanks


You must not clone with option --branches=none otherwise you are doing a flat migration without branch support and after you can't initialize other branches.

I don't really get what is your "CacheFull" error (a TFS server error or a git-tfs one? worth opening a github issue in git-tfs issue tracker?) but if you want to migrate all branches/history, --branches=all is your best option.
But if have a memory error, or a transient error preventing you to do a full clone, or if you stopped the process after at least 1 changeset fetched, maybe you could try to continue by running the exact same command again but with the --resumable option. git-tfs will try to continue where it stopped. If you still have the repository locally, try that first.

Another strategy, if you want to be a little more easy on resources used is to clone only the main branch (letting git-tfs initialize only the merged branches when needed) with parameter --branches=auto (or no parameter because that's the default behavior).

and then initialize and fetch all the other branches with:
git tfs branch --init --all

I highly encourage you to try also the development version of git-tfs ( https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/?tab=readme-ov-file#get-git-tfs or directly to get the artifact: https://ci.appveyor.com/project/pmiossec/git-tfs-v2qcm/branch/master/artifacts)

I merged PR https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/pull/1493 , still not released, and some users gets better results with it.
Note: You could post a feedback comment in the PR. The more I have is the better. I'm waiting more feedback to maybe do a new release...


Now I've tried using git fetch -i $/Project1/Releases/2.2 but I got an error saying [...]

You are trying to fetch a branch which is not initialized so git-tfs is putting you in the wrong direction (by asking you to use the bootstrap command) because it think that is due to another reason.
Managing branches (initializing, deleting,...) is done with the git tfs branch command.
But I really don't know how it behave in a clone done with --branches=none. I don't think it's something to try.
Summary: As said before, do a fresh clone with --branches=all or --branches=auto and maybe with the development version of git-tfs that could bring better result.

I've started running the new version that you suggested me, I got a lot of "no history found for item [path]" is this correct? now I wait to see if the previous blocking changeset is still blocking, otherwise there would be a simple way to skip changesets? I've seen that the documentation use --ignore-branches-regex but this applies to commit as well? source: https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/issues/1033

You can try like as below:

Use the option '--branches=all' o the 'git tfs clone' command to fetch all the TFS branches into a local git repository.
git-tfs clone <tfs-url> $project .


In the local git repository, Use the 'git branch' command with the option '-d' (shortcut for --delete) or '-D' (shortcut for --delete --force) to delete the unneeded branches.
git branch -D <branch-name>


Then connect and push to the remote git repository.



I've done that but it get in loop on C4974 changeset and loops for hours

@advapi, What is the detailed error message you get? And which steps does the error occur on?

I've tried with the version you've suggested to me , unfortunatelly after 5h of fetching I got stucked on the same point. it seems that it loops on the same branch
    The name of the local branch will be : PROJECTUnivers/Releases/2.2
Git local branch will be : PROJECTUnivers/Releases/2.2
Looking for changeset 4976 in git repository...
Looking for changeset 4976 in git repository: CacheIsFull, stopped lookin
Looking for root changeset tree on $/PROJECTNG/Releases/2.2
Looking for root changeset for branch:$/PROJECTNG/Releases/2.2
Looking to find branch '$/PROJECTNG/Releases/2.2' in all TFS branches..
Found parent branch : $/PROJECT2/PROJECTUnivers/Main
Merge: `Delete, SourceRename` C4976 `$/PROJECT2/PROJECTUnivers/Releas
Found C4976 on branch $/PROJECT2/PROJECTUnivers/Releases/2.2
Found original branch '$/PROJECT2/PROJECTUnivers/Releases/2.2' (renam
Looking for root changeset for branch:$/PROJECT2/PROJECTUnivers/Relea
Looking to find branch '$/PROJECT2/PROJECTUnivers/Releases/2.2' in al
Found parent branch : $/PROJECT2/PROJECTUnivers/Main
Merge: `Rename` C4976 `$/PROJECTNG/Releases/2.2` Source `Delete, Source
Found C4976 on branch $/PROJECTNG/Releases/2.2
Found original branch '$/PROJECTNG/Releases/2.2' (renamed in branch '$/
Looking for root changeset for branch:$/PROJECTNG/Releases/2.2
Looking to find branch '$/PROJECTNG/Releases/2.2' in all TFS branches..
Found parent branch : $/PROJECT2/PROJECTUnivers/Main
Merge: `Delete, SourceRename` C4976 `$/PROJECT2/PROJECTUnivers/Releas
Found C4976 on branch $/PROJECT2/PROJECTUnivers/Releases/2.2
Begin process of creating branch for remote :$/PROJECT2/PROJECTUniver
The name of the local branch will be : PROJECTUnivers/Releases/2.2
Git local branch will be : PROJECTUnivers/Releases/2.2
Looking for changeset 4976 in git repository...
Looking for changeset 4976 in git repository: CacheIsFull, stopped lookin
Looking for root changeset tree on $/PROJECTNG/Releases/2.2
Looking for root changeset for branch:$/PROJECTNG/Releases/2.2
Looking to find branch '$/PROJECTNG/Releases/2.2' in all TFS branches..
Found parent branch : $/PROJECT2/PROJECTUnivers/Main
Merge: `Delete, SourceRename` C4976 `$/PROJECT2/PROJECTUnivers/Releas
Found C4976 on branch $/PROJECT2/PROJECTUnivers/Releases/2.2
Found original branch '$/PROJECT2/PROJECTUnivers/Releases/2.2' (renam
Looking for root changeset for branch:$/PROJECT2/PROJECTUnivers/Relea
Looking to find branch '$/PROJECT2/PROJECTUnivers/Releases/2.2' in al
Found parent branch : $/PROJECT2/PROJECTUnivers/Main
Merge: `Rename` C4976 `$/PROJECTNG/Releases/2.2` Source `Delete, Source
Found C4976 on branch $/PROJECTNG/Releases/2.2
Found original branch '$/PROJECTNG/Releases/2.2' (renamed in branch '$/
Looking for root changeset for branch:$/PROJECTNG/Releases/2.2
Looking to find branch '$/PROJECTNG/Releases/2.2' in all TFS branches..
Found parent branch : $/PROJECT2/PROJECTUnivers/Main
Merge: `Delete, SourceRename` C4976 `$/PROJECT2/PROJECTUnivers/Releas
Found C4976 on branch $/PROJECT2/PROJECTUnivers/Releases/2.2
Begin process of creating branch for remote :$/PROJECT2/PROJECTUniver
The name of the local branch will be : PROJECTUnivers/Releases/2.2

I've tried to stop and resume but when I do that I got

Command run:git tfs clone http://s1:8080/tfs/PROJECT%20univers/
$/PROJECT2/PROJECTUnivers/M No authors file used. git-tfs version
0.34.11.0 (TFS client library 16.0.0.0 (MS)) (64-bit) Establishing TFS credentials using user identity... Identity-based VSS credentials
created. Looking for all branches... GitTfs.Core.GitTfsException:
error: no tfs remote to use found in parent commits.    at
GitTfs.Util.GitTfsCommandRunner.Run(GitTfsCommand command, IList1 args) in C:\gittfs\src\GitTfs\Ut    at GitTfs.GitTfs.Main(GitTfsCommand command, IList1 unparsedArgs) in
C:\gittfs\src\GitTfs\GitTfs.cs:l    at GitTfs.GitTfs.Run(IList`1 args)
in C:\gittfs\src\GitTfs\GitTfs.cs:line 44    at
GitTfs.Program.Main(String[] args) in
C:\gittfs\src\GitTfs\Program.cs:line 25 error: no tfs remote to use
found in parent commits. You may be able to resolve this problem.

Checkout a current tfs branch
Use '-i' option to define which one to use. All the logs could be found in the log file:
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\git-tfs\git-tfs_log.txt


Checking the list-remote-branches the 2.2 is the first one it breaks on
$/PROJECT2/PROJECTUnivers/Main [*]
|
+- $/PROJECTNG/Releases/2.2
|
+- $/PROJECTNG/Releases/2.3.0.4
| ...a lot of others
Is there a way I can set a max retry or try to skip that 2.2?
Thanks

Can you share more details of what steps you have done?
